# Unable to execute powershell GUI using wpf

Tags: wpf, powershell, user-interface

I am trying to build a GUI (a simple one click button) for some daily tasks we have to do at work. I started off with a disk space checking .ps1 script built into GUI as below

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

[xml]$XAMLWindow = '
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        Title="Windows Management Tool" Height="450" Width="600" Background="Gray">
    <Grid>

        <Button Name="DiskSpace" Content="Check Available Disk Space" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" Margin="56,194,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="181"/>


           </Grid>
</Window>

'

$Reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $XAMLWindow)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $Reader )


$DiskSpace = $Window.FindName('DiskSpace')



$DiskSpace.Add_Click({
.\checkDiskSpaceOnMulti.ps1
})


$Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Below is the code for checkDiskSpaceOnMulti.ps1 that I embedded into GUI

```
$file = get-Content C:\list.txt  

foreach ( $args in $file) { 
get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $args -Filter "Drivetype=3"  |  
ft SystemName,DeviceID,VolumeName,@{Label="Total SIze";Expression={$_.Size / 1gb -as [int] }},@{Label="Free Size";Expression={$_.freespace / 1gb -as [int] }} -autosize 
}
```

and when I click the button on GUI, I get below error. checkDiskSpaceOnMulti.ps1 works perfectly as I need, when using from powershell ISE. Problem is only when using with the GUI script.

```
.\checkDiskSpaceOnMulti.ps1 : The term '.\checkDiskSpaceOnMulti.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At H:\Powershell\Powershell\Windows_Utility_Tool.ps1:54 char:1
+ .\checkDiskSpaceOnMulti.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\checkDiskSpaceOnMulti.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Also suggest me a good tool for PoSh GUI developing tool.

Comment: That is not winforms, that is wpf

Comment: Don't use `$args` as variable name because it is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#args) in PowerShell.

Comment: I'd **strongly** recommend against building UIs in PowerShell. Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: Its not exactly GUI'ing the PoSh. I am only trying to get the .ps1 executable from a GUI window with a single click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you'd be better of using a multiline textbox using a monospaced font in the window to show the results. Also, since the code to run is quite small, I would put it inside a function and run that on the button click:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

[xml]$XAMLWindow = @'
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        Title="Windows Management Tool" Height="450" Width="600" Background="Gray">

    <Grid Margin="0,10,0,0">

        <TextBox Name="ResultBox" Height="300" Width="500" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" FontFamily="Consolas"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>

        <Button Name="DiskSpace" Content="Check Available Disk Space" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Height="43" Margin="40,330,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="181"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
'@

$Reader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $XAMLWindow
$Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($Reader)

function checkDiskSpaceOnMulti {
    $textBox = $Window.FindName("ResultBox")
    $textBox.Clear()

    # read the file as string array and skip empty lines
    # UPDATE: force the result of Get-Content to be an array if only one computer is listed
    $file = @(Get-Content 'C:\list.txt') | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }

    # fill the textbox with the results
    $textBox.Text = foreach ($computer in $file) {
        # add a test to see if the computer can be reached
        if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet) {
            Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $computer -Filter "Drivetype=3" |
            Format-Table SystemName, DeviceID, VolumeName,
                         @{Label="Total Size";Expression={$_.Size / 1gb -as [int] }},
                         @{Label="Free Size" ;Expression={$_.Freespace / 1gb -as [int] }} -AutoSize | Out-String
        }
        else {
            "WARNING: Computer '$computer' is off-line or does not exist.`r`n"
        }
    }
}

$DiskSpace = $Window.FindName("DiskSpace")
$DiskSpace.Add_Click({ checkDiskSpaceOnMulti })

$Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

The above will result in a window like this:

[image]

Hope that helps

Comment: Hey, thanks for very detailed explanation. I am new to PoSh and the way you have shown the code is easy for me to understand. However, the result is returning True from Test-Connection instead of diskspace and I dont see anything wrog with Line 33 either. what am I missing?

```
WARNING: Computer 'True' is off-line or does not exist.
```

Comment: @JayaSankarYakkala I have edited the line that reads the text file and removes empty or whitespace-only lines to `$file = (Get-Content 'C:\list.txt') | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }`. The former (shorter) version works on my PowerShell version 5.1, but perhaps you have a different version?

Comment: I have 5.x too.

Comment: @JsJ In that case, what is in the `C:\list.txt` other than a list of computer names, each on a separate line? Does it contain the word `True` perhaps?

Comment: computername is D-V0-12, no spaces nothing. In case of multiple computer names, I put them in separate lines.

Comment: @JsJ I found the problem. It happened when only one pc is listed in the `C:\list.txt`. By doing that, the result of `Get-Content` has only one element and then Powershell flattens that to become just a string. The code wants an array, so I only had to put an `@` character in front to force it to be an array. `$file = (Get-Content 'C:\list.txt')` --> `$file = @(Get-Content 'C:\list.txt')`

Comment: That looks like the issue, it worked the moment I added more than one computers to the  list. TQVM :)